# Как отключить кэш в modx?

Tags: modx

на этапе разработки надо отключить кэширование, так как постоянно надо самому очищать через админку. Это можно как то сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В системных настройках в разделе кеширование

Answer (score 0):

в начале сниппета поставить восклицательный знак. 
к примеру `[[!snipet]]`
или
в ресурсах убрать галочку не кешировать.